# How to active loader at bootstrap carousel 3 item active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, loader

How to activate any loader animation at bootstrap carousel item index 2 and stop at index3 when ever index 2 active loader start and when index 4 active loader stops. also i want to reducing this loader size too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var progressbar = $('#progress_bar');
    max = parseInt(progressbar.attr('max'), 10);
    time = (1000 / max) * 2;
    value = progressbar.val();

    var loading = function() {
        var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart');
        if (value >= max) {
            value = 0;
            $ppc.removeClass('gt-50');
        } else {
            value += 1;
        }

        addValue = progressbar.val(value);

        $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');
        var deg = 360 * value / 10;
        if (value > 5) {
            $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
        }

        $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
        $('.ppc-ball').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
        $('.ppc-percents span').html(value + '');
    };

    setInterval(loading, time);
 
 
 
   
});
```

```css
.bar {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #52b4ed;
    width: 0%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: none;
    z-index: 11;
    position: relative;
 
}

/* Pie Chart */
.progress-pie-chart {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #024369;
    position: relative;
}

.progress-pie-chart.gt-50 {
background:red;



}

.ppc-progress {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    top: calc(50% - 100px);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}

.gt-50 .ppc-progress {
    clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
}

.ppc-progress-fill {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    top: calc(50% - 100px);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  

background:red;






}

.ppc-ball {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.ppc-ball:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
   
background: rgba(82,180,237,1);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82,180,237,1) 0%, rgba(7,120,219,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(82,180,237,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(7,120,219,0)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82,180,237,1) 0%, rgba(7,120,219,0) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82,180,237,1) 0%, rgba(7,120,219,0) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82,180,237,1) 0%, rgba(7,120,219,0) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(82,180,237,1) 0%, rgba(7,120,219,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#52b4ed', endColorstr='#0778db', GradientType=1 );

    top: -7px;
    left: 85px;
}

.gt-50 .ppc-progress-fill {
    clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px);
    background: #024369;
}

.ppc-percents {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 173.91304px / 2);
    top: calc(50% - 173.91304px / 2);
    width: 173.91304px;
    height: 173.91304px;
    background: #052b4e;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

.ppc-percents span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fc7114;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(248, 94, 41, 1);
}

.pcc-percents-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.progress-pie-chart {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

                 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol> 
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item">
                        <div class="container">
               <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>First slide label</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                        <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                        <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar" />

<div style="margin:0 auto;">
 
 <div class="bar_container">
    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="pbar" class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="0">
            <div class="ppc-progress">
                <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ppc-percents">
                <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
                    <span>0</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ppc-ball"></div>
        </div>
        <progress style="display: none" id="progress_bar" value="0" max="10"></progress>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Don't understand what you want to achieve, could you explain it in details?

Comment: Forget everything, you just help me how to reduce the above loader size.

Comment: Then you should edit your question for actual information.